# SIR phase plane r

Tags: r, differential-equations

4. [~15%] Using the function ode() from the deSolve package, compute the solution of the SIR model
   with N = 100, β = 0.02, γ = 1, initial conditions S(0) = 99.9, I(0) = 0.1, and a vector of time points
   ranging from 0 to 20. Plot the solution in the (S,I) phase plane.

any help with this question?

```
library(deSolve)

beta<-0.02
gamma<-1
N<-100
initial<-c(S=99.9, I=0.1, R=1000)
parms<-c(beta=beta, gamma=gamma, N=N)

times<-seq(0, 20 ,by=0.1)

output<-ode(y=initial, times=times, func=SIR_dydt, parms=parms)

plot(output[, "S", "I"], type="l", xlab="t", ylab="No. individuals, main="SIR solutions")
legend("topright", legend = c("S", "I"), lty = 1, col = c("blue", "red"))
```

tried this code but got this error

Error in checkFunc(Func2, times, y, rho) :
Model function must return a list

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The error indicates that the function `SIR_dydt` has a wrong return value. So to answer the question, we need the code of function `SIR_dydt`.

Comment: Does this look right? Thanks!!

SIR_dydt<-function(t, y, parms) {
beta<-parms[1]
gamma<-parms[2]
S<-y[1]
I<-y[2]
N<-S+I
dSdt<--beta*S*I
dIdt<-beta*S*I-gamma*I
return(list(c(dSdt, dIdt)))
}

N<-100
beta<-0.02
gamma<-1

#inital conditions:
Szero<-99.9
Izero<-0.1

#time points
steps<-seq(from=0, to=20, by=1)

SIRsolution<-ode(c(Szero,Izero), steps, SIR_dydt, c(N, beta, gamma))

plot(SIRsolution[,2], SIRsolution[,3], type="l", xlab="S", ylab="I", col="magenta", main="SI phase plane for SIR model")

Comment: You can edit your question to include the additional code.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the original question was incomplete and the code in an additional comment had some errors, so I tried to make a synthesis.

A few points:

- The variable `N` was redundant
- the parameter vector contained `N` as first element, so that the parameters were confused. In general, it is more robust to pass parameters and state variables by named vectors and not by their position.
- some multiplication signs were missing
- increased the number of `steps` to obtain a smooth figure.

In addition to the 2D state diagram, package **phaseR** can be used to add an optional flow field.

```r
library("deSolve")

SIR_dydt <- function(t, y, parms) { 
   beta  <- parms[1] 
   gamma <- parms[2] 
   S <- y[1] 
   I <- y[2] 
   dSdt <- -beta * S * I 
   dIdt <-  beta * S * I - gamma * I 
   return(list(c(dSdt, dIdt))) 
} 
 
beta <- 0.02 
gamma <- 1 
## inital conditions: 
Szero <- 99.9 
Izero <- 0.1 

## time points 
steps <- seq(from = 0, to = 20, by = .1) 
SIRsolution <- ode(c(S = Szero, I = Izero), steps, SIR_dydt, c(beta, gamma)) 
 
## time series
plot(SIRsolution)

## state diagram
par(mfrow = c(1, 1)) # reset plotting parameters
plot(SIRsolution[,2], SIRsolution[,3], 
  type = "l", xlab = "S", ylab="I", 
  col = "magenta", main = "SI phase plane for SIR model")

### === additional goody, add flow field ========================
library("phaseR")
 
init <- c(s = Szero, I = Izero)
parms <- c(beta, gamma)

plot(SIRsolution[, c(2, 3)], type = "l", col = "magenta", 
     xlim = c(0, 100), ylim=c(0, 20),
     main="SI phase plane for SIR model")
flow <- flowField(SIR_dydt, xlim = c(0, 100), ylim = c(0, 20),
          parameters = parms)
```

[image: Phase portrait with flow field]

Comment: In StackOverflow, "thank you comments" are often considered as obsolete. The official way is to accept an answer. You are not obliged to do so, but it helps others to see that a question was solved. You will then also get 2 bonus points yourself.

Comment: Another suggestion: if you edit your code, so that it is complete and reproduces the original error, someone may consider to remove the negative vote from your question. I considered to edit it myself, but the code in your comment produces another error.